# Show only some inline styles with strip_tags()

Tags: php, html-parsing, strip-tags

I have some really messy HTML with lots of `span`s and other tags.

I'm trying to only keep `<span style="font-weight: bold">` while removing the other such span tags.

I have this so far:

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<br>,<quote>,<code>,<pre>,<ul>,<li>,<ol>,<span>');
```

I want to remove `<span>` because it adds all the other `span`s globally, I'd just want the `span`s with `font-style` in them. How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest using a DOM parser, and [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) would work pretty good with this particular exercise. Or run it through a headless browser (is there one for PHP?) or through an actual browser with some JS that captures the content after filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip_tags` can't do this.

Take a look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org).  It's designed exactly for this use case.  You can give it a whitelist of tags and attributes to allow.  It also has basic CSS parsing, allowing you to [whitelist and blacklist CSS properties](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#CSS).

In this case, you'd probably do something like:

```
// This has not been tested, but should work
$configuration->set('HTML.Allowed', 'br,quote,code,pre,ul,li,ol,span[style]');
$configuration->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'font-weight');
```

Now, you're still going to be left with some extra span tags.  You've suggested that you simply want them gone.  This is going to be a bit stickier.  You want to use a DOM manipulation tool to find each useless span, capture the contents, remove the span, then insert the contents where the span was.  [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) was already pointed out, and [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) should also do the trick.  PHP's own [DOM extension](http://php.net/book.dom) can also do this, but it's going to be *much* more of a bear.